# Zooming in browser being inferred as Mobile in responsive design

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a web page that renders a drop down. By design, I want to disable the drop down in Mobile. I have used view port size as the criteria to determine whether the current device is Mobile or not. Whenever I am zooming in to 200 percent or higher, the viewport size is reducing and it is inferred as mobile device. Hence, the drop down does not render. I do not want to use navigator.userAgent for this purpose. Any other workaround for this?

Comment: Can you share your CSS for doing the media queries?

Comment: I have no media queries as of now. I have used js to just straightaway not render the dropdown when its mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whenever I am zooming in to 200 percent or higher, the viewport size is reducing and it is inferred as mobile device.

What you're describing is the difference between device pixels and CSS pixels while zoomed. As the browser zoom increases, so does the ratio of CSS to device pixels. This is how most browsers are designed to work, and it's what visitors generally expect.

So, if your page width is 1,000px:

- at 125% zoom, your CSS pixels will be 800px (1,000 / 1.25)
- at 150% zoom, your CSS pixels will be 667px (1,000 / 1.5)
- at 200% zoom, your CSS pixels will be 500px (1,000 / 2)

If you want to zoom the page WITHOUT affecting CSS pixels, you could potentially do something custom using the CSS `transform` property.

```
body {
   transform: scale(2);
   transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

The problem that I foresee with this approach is that it will necessarily require side-scrolling.

WCAG 2.1 SC 1.4.10 requires that:

> Content can be presented without loss of information or functionality, and without requiring scrolling in two dimensions for vertical scrolling content at a width equivalent to 320 CSS pixels
> https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/reflow.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the media query `max-device-width` which gets the actual device rendering screen size rather than than the viewport size.

For example:

```
.nav-menu {
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share any example/

Comment: added example for css media query